# Correct way to calculate a complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I have
$$
\int_{[-i,i]} \sin(z)\,dz
$$

Parametrizing the segment $[-i,i]$ I have, if $t\in[0,1]$
$$
z(t) = it + (1-t)(-i) = 2it-i, \quad \dot{z}(t) = 2i.
$$
So
$$
\int_{[-i,i]} \sin(z)\,dz = \int_0^1 \sin(2it-i)2i\, dt = -\cos(2it-i)|_0^1 = 0.
$$

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are! Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

Sine is analytic function, so you can also use [Cauchy's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) theorem. 
$$
\int_{[-i, i]} \sin z\ dz = -\left . \cos z \right |_{-i}^i = 0
$$

Comment: Analytical is the same as holomorphic?

Comment: In fact – yes. All holomorphic functions are analytic, and vice versa. But conceptually, one stands for differentiability, another for power series representation. Later on one can prove that two concepts describe same class of functions.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you.